# Name of Excel formula in different languages in xlsx format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx

I generated Excel file in my application in **xlsx** format. Unfortunately if I use English name of the function and my Excel is not set to English then Excel identifies it as bad function name. Simillar situation does not happen in **xls** format.

Is it any way to avoid this problem?

Configuration of Excel itself is not acceptable solution as client should not be forced to make changes in his environment.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Your assertion is not true. Office Open XML stores Excel formulas always in en_us notation, never in other locale notations. The changing to locale notations occurs only in Excel GUI. But there is a difference between formula cell content and string cell content. A formula is **not** simply a string which starts with "=".

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you for information. I use external library to generate excel files and I am not sure if it is possible to distinguish between formula cell content and string cell content. Is it possible to explicitly inform Excel that it is formula which should be processed or it is on file encoding level (some metatags) that cannot be changed from gui.

Comment: This depends on the external library you are using. In Office Open XML (the format of `*.xlsx` files) the XML for a string cell looks like: `<c r="D2" t="s"><v>49</v></c>`. There the `t="s"` means type string and the value 49 refers to position 49 in the shared strings table. A formula cell looks like this: `<c r="AI8"><f>COUNTIF($B8:$AF8,"Pr")</f><v>5</v></c>`. As you see, there is a special element tag `f` for formulas and the value 5 is the last calculated result.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has its own way for translating the formulas from every language to English. You should not take care of that, it does it quite well. Thus a file in Spanish Excel can be read in French Excel without further adjustments.

E.g., see the German formula "SUMME" in F1. It is translated by excel to "SUM", when you ask about it -> see the immediate window on the right.

[image]

The only thing you should avoid is formula like this:
`activecell.FormulaR1C1Local= "=SUMME(Z(8)S(-2):Z(9)S(-2))"`, because it takes the local formula as a string and Excel cannot find a way to translate "SUMME" to "SUM".